# Stopping a Singularity container

Tags: singularity-container

I would like to stop a running singularity container, similarly to how I can stop a docker container:

```
$ docker run --name my-container
$ docker stop my-container
```

I am running Singularity like this:

```
$ singularity run image.img
```

Thank you!
Mattia

Answer (score 2):

When using `singularity run ...` and you want to stop the process, you just have to use `kill $singularity_PID` or `pkill singularity` to kill all singularity processes by your user.

You can also use `singularity instance start /path/to/image.sif instance_name` to get more docker-like behavior. Then you can use `singularity instance stop instance_name`. You can also use `singularity shell instance://instance_name` to get a shell in the running environment, which is not possible with `singularity run`.